# jQuery click even in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, click

I'm having an issue in firefox with the jQuery click event-

```
$('div#return-menu').click(function () {
    hidePainting();
    alert();
});
```

This is supposed to reveal a menu with the hidePainting(); method, but it doesn't even fire as verified by the alert() not firing.

Brought div#return-menu to the front with a high z-index and tried to ensure that no other elements are covering it, but none of this has fixed the problem.

What I have observed is that the text in div#return-menu does not bring up the I-beam pointer on mouseover, however it does when I put the element on the menu (where I don't want it) and the click fires successfully, which is also the case in Chrome.

Is this a problem anyone else has seen or knows about? It's a frustratingly small but debilitating problem. I can post more info code or answer questions if it helps.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: in firefox, alert needs one argument

`alert("this works");`

Comment: thx for your response. I tried adding an argument and it still doesn't fire.

Comment: use Firefox to debug, and there is strong chance that hidePainting() method may be reached but the method may have an error, because of which the alert() statement is not reached.

Comment: do you use firebug to debug it?

Comment: will give it a go and let u know. cheers

Comment: please provide more code, the one you posted looks correct (except the `alert()`)

Comment: I commented out the other method and the alert still doesn't fire. Will carry on with firebug.

Comment: I've found the issue now. There was a div covering the element I'm cliking, I just hadn't found it in the end. I've reduced the size of the element so that the clicked element is no longer covered and the click even is picked up now. I'm not 100% sure whether uncovering the div was necessary or if I could have altered the z-index of the correctly identified offending element. Thanks for all your time.